# CSS triangle + square at 100%

Tags: css, css-shapes, responsive

I would like this square and triangle, shown on the link at 100% page width (responsive).

http://www.jsfiddle.net/webtiki/x9cxz423/199/

```
.btn {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
height: 50px; width:50%;
text-align: center;
color: white;
background: gray;
line-height: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
padding-bottom:15%;
background-clip:content-box;
overflow:hidden;
}
.btn:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top:50px; left: 0;
background-color:inherit;
padding-bottom:50%; width:57.7%;
z-index:-1;

-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
-ms-transform-origin:0 0;
transform-origin:0 0;

-webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);;
-ms-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
}
/** FOR THE DEMO **/
body{background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-    1.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

I can't seem to get it work at all, can anyone help me out please?

Thank you

Luke

Comment: So uh...what is the problem you're facing? It seems to work - I mean, I see a square with a triangle pointing underneath it...

Comment: I want it to work at 100% width.. it doesnt work when i put 100% width in

Comment: Increase the padding-bottom to like 30% on the button and give it a width of 100%.   http://jsfiddle.net/mvLdf75t/

Comment: thank you user2677350

is there an easy way to make the triangle more ... shallow? squish it a bit?

Comment: add vertical scale ? http://jsfiddle.net/x9cxz423/990/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your code, now is responsive too!

```css
.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px; 
    min-width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: gray;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom:30%;
    background-clip:content-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:50px; left: 0;
    background-color:inherit;
    padding-bottom:50%; width:57.7%;
    z-index:-1;
    
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
}
/** FOR THE DEMO **/
body{background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Hello!</a>
```